# Angular - using ng-pluralize with range

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to use ng-pluralize to specify text for a range of numbers?

For example, I have a day count and I'd like to display today, yesterday, this week, or n days ago.

```
<ng-pluralize 
    count="daysOld" 
    when="{'0': 'today', 
           '1': 'yesterday',
           // '2 to 7': 'this week', 
           'other': '{} days ago.'}">
</ng-pluralize>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its better to use your own directive with ng-switch or ng-if.
Or you can create that array by program, where 2 to 7 all index will hold same message and use that array here.

Comment: Thanks, I used ng-if for the 2-7 case in the end.